# Set a specific value of an attribute in database - Asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Working in Asp.net MVC 5.

I have a model/table called `Cars`. I want the user to fill in the "New Car" form which has the following properties:

```
Name, Brand Name, Sales Price, Number Available.
```

All of this information is being stored in the database.

How to set the default value of `NumberAvailable` to 1 so there is no need make a field for `NumberAvailable` in the "New Car" form but the attribute/column `NumberAvailable` gets the value set to 1 in the database with every entry?

I've tried adding `[DefaultValue(1)]` on the attribute

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }
```

But that doesn't work!

I've also tried to set the default value of the column to 1 in the design view of the table and update the script it didn't work either.

Comment: Do it in the default constructor for the class - `public class Car { public Car() { NumberAvailable  = 1; } public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; } }`

Comment: ***WHAT*** database? Each database differs slightly in how they handle different aspects of data storage and manipulation - please add the proper **tag** to your question to clear this up!

Comment: Thanks Stephen it works.
Marc I've updated the question tags. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP.NET MVC5

Following the comment of Stephen
To set a specific value of an attribute without asking the user to fill in create a constructor in the class.

```
public Car() { NumberAvailable = 1; } 
public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }
```

The value of NumberAvailable is set to 1 whenever any entry is made via new form.

The constructor is created in the Model class. The complete model class is as follows:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(04)]
    public string Yom { get; set; }   //Year Of Manufacture = YOM

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string SalePrice { get; set; }


    public Car() { NumberAvailable = 1; } 
    public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; } 
}
```